# QlikView load table from Excel - merge

Tags: excel, import, scripting, qlikview

All,

I am loading a table from excel into QLikView using

- New
- Edit Script
- Table Files as datasource --> browse my .xls file

my .xls document is a table with monthly sales: rows are companies, columns are months in 2012 Jan to Dec. Into QlikView, import gives me 13 tables: one with the companies names, and 12 with sales for each months.

1. how do i get a single table on import, very similar to the table in Excel ? what is it not the default presentation mode ?
2. if there is no mean to load the .xls into one single table, how can i merge the tables as to get a single table ?

thanks

---

my script looks like this

```
LOAD [Corporate Account], 
     Month, 
     Jan, 
     Feb, 
     Mar, 
     Apr, 
     May, 
     Jun, 
     Jul, 
     Aug, 
     Sep, 
     Oct, 
     Nov, 
     Dec
FROM
[F:\WORK\corp_account.xls]
(biff, embedded labels, table is Sheet1$);
```

and it brings one QlikView table per month plus one for accounts name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is to first create the table with the above script. Then, right click -> new sheet object -> Table Box opens a window where it is possible too select fields to be included in the view. Add all to get the exact match with original excel one.

Answer (score 0):

By 13 tables you probably mean 13 fields.

Solution to your problem is a `crosstable` - e.g. add following line above your LOAD statement:

```
CrossTable(Month, Sales)
```

As a result, your table will have 3 fields: Corporate Account, Month, Sales.
I strongly recommend putting year together with month, because if you have year and month on separate rows, it is much more difficult to work with crosstables.